# Patch Deform in Blender

Tags: modeling

[image][image][image]I hope you are all good. As I am new to Blender, I was wondering if there is a modifier that can perform an object deform similar to 3DS max patch deform modifier.

I am currently building a track and I am using the curve modifier to model the kerbs but there is always some weird tilting going as the curve does not have the same normals as the surface it has been separated from. Does anyone know a workaround this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Many thanks,
Stav

Comment: Hello and welcome. For those who don't know it might be worth it explaining what the *Patch Deform* modifier does and illustrate its effect, so that anyone that knows Blender may help, even those not familiar with 3DS Max. Perhaps also illustrate the issue you are facing, there may be workaround solutions that don't involve recreating 3DS Max feature set. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: It looks pretty similar to what you can do with the Mesh Deform modifier, or with the Wrapping Tool addon, or with the Tissue addon, I guess it depends on the case, could you please show a concrete case ?

Comment: See this video on Wrapping Tools: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1A22jfG-sc

Comment: Hi guys, thank you both for your prompt reply. So the 3 images I uploaded hopefully clarify what the small issue is. I am using the curve modifier and at the start of the kerb you can see there is a tilt which raises the kerb higher than the verge and at the end of the kerb the opposite happens where the kerb is actually under the verge. What I wanted to do is follow the curve but with the same slope as the verge. Thanks again

Comment: The closest to Patch Deform Modifier is Surface Deform Modifier in Blender https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/modifiers/deform/surface_deform.html. However it doesn't work with Curves, but Meshes. You could try modularize your path into tiles then use Array Modifier and Curve modifier next.

Comment: Hi @RumenBelev, thank you for your response. What exactly do you mean by modularizing the path into tiles? Sorry for the silly question, I am still trying to get my head around blender. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. That means to make a cross-section strip of your path including the curb, which can then replicate in a long straight path via Array. Then using the curve modifier you can bend that straight path the way you want.

Comment: Switch the curve from Twist Method > Minimum to Z-Up, it it doesn't help please share your file

Comment: Hi @moonboots, thank you for your reply. I did try this which helped into an extend but did not resolve the issue. I actually found an addon called magic curve which extracts the curve from a surface and it maintains its based on that surface. This sort it my issue. Once again thank you all for the recommendations.